Exponential of Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process squared
Given an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process $d r(t)=-\kappa r(t)+ g dW_t$, the expectation value of the exponential of the OU is a well-known result
\begin{equation}
    \langle e^{a r(t)} \rangle=e^{a^2 \sigma^2/2}
\end{equation}
where we have used $\langle r(t) \rangle=0$ and $\langle r(t)^2 \rangle=\sigma^2$ at the long-time limit $t\rightarrow \infty$.
What can we say about the square of the OU process?
\begin{equation}
    \langle e^{a r^2(t)} \rangle
\end{equation}
How should one proceed to compute it? Taylor expand the exponential and using Wick's theorem seems like an arduous task.

completing the square?

and what would be the idea behind it? i don't understand

$P(r)$ is a Gaussian, so the integration can be done, st least for small and negative $a$

I do not think that $\mathbb E[ar(t)]=0$ which you write as
$\langle ar(t)\rangle=0$ is true. That mean
is obtained from the explicit solution of the OU SDE which is well known to  be
$$
r(t)=e^{-\kappa t}\left\{r(0)+g\int_0^te^{\kappa s}\,dW_s\right\}\,.
$$
Obviously
$$
\mathbb E\big[\sqrt{a}\,r(t)\big]=\sqrt{a}\,e^{-\kappa t}\,r(0)=:\mu(t)\,.
$$
It is also well-known that the variance of $\sqrt{a}\,r(t)$ is
$$a\,g^2e^{-2\kappa t}\int_0^te^{2\kappa s}\,ds=a\,g^2\frac{1-e^{-2\kappa t}}{2\kappa}=:\sigma^2(t)\,.$$
To simplify the notation I write $\mu,\sigma$ from now on, and $\sqrt{a}\,r(t)=\mu+\sigma X$ with a standard normal $X\,.$
Then,
\begin{align}
&\mathbb E[e^{a\,r^2(t)}]=\mathbb E[e^{(\mu+\sigma X)^2}]=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{(\mu+\sigma x)^2}e^{-x^2/2}\,dx\\[2mm]
&=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{\mu^2+2\mu\sigma x}e^{-(1-2\sigma^2)\,x^2/2}\,dx\,\\[2mm]
&=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi(1-2\sigma^2)}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\exp\left(\mu^2+\tfrac{2\mu\sigma y}{\sqrt{1-2\sigma^2}}\right)\,e^{-y^2/2}\,dy\\[2mm]
&=\frac1{\sqrt{1-2\sigma^2}}\exp\left(\mu^2+\tfrac{2\mu^2\sigma^2}{1-2\sigma^2}\right)\,.
\end{align}
This is defined only when
$$
\sigma^2<\frac12\,.
$$

I think when the OP writes $\langle ar(t) \rangle = 0$ they mean $\lim_{t \to \infty} E(ar_t) = 0$

@JoseAvilez Thanks for reading OP so carefully. That is of course true. There is however still a bit of a mess in the notation: The limit of $\langle r^2(t)\rangle$ should be $g^2$ not $\sigma^2,.$

I build a python code to simulate the SDE and check the averaged quantity and they agree, so the result is correct. Thank you!
